# How to make a link to local file in Java?

Tags: java, file, audio

I want to show a link to an audio file inside a panel. It should be played when the user click it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try something? Thought of something?

Comment: You mean via GUI? You have couple of options to create GUI application in Java: Swing, AWT, SWT, JavaFX.

Comment: Wrong site - you are looking for a developers for hire website, for which there are plenty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `clickable label` that open the audio file, here is an example:

```
JLabel lblFileLink = new JLabel("Audio File Title");

// To indicate the the link is clickable
lblFileLink.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

lblFileLink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(
                        new File("AUDIO FILE PATH"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want to make the link similar to HTML link you can do the following:

```
JLabel lblFileLink =
   new JLabel("<HTML><BODY><a href=\"\">somefile.mp3</a></BODY></HTML>");
```

Comment: +1 Add Color.blue to lblFileLink to simulate a link.

Comment: Modified my answer to accommodate your comment :)